# Using compare operators on alphanumeric numbers

Tags: mysql

I've a list of items with values between 1A and 100Z *(1A, 2A, 3A, ..., 100A, 1B, 2B, 3B, ..., 100Z)*.

**How can I fetch all items (f.i.) between 43A and 64X?**

I've tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_with_items WHERE column_with_value <= 43A AND column_with_value >= 64X
```

and this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_with_items WHERE column_with_value BETWEEN 43A AND 64X
```

But it doesn't work so simple :)

**So is there a way to compare Alphanumeric strings?**

Thanks!

Comment: Keep the sequence with ID's in the table in appropriate order, then join with you table and filter by ID.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, The solution you offer is what i'm trying to avoid. But if this is the only way i can do so i  have to do it like this. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score -2):

Did you try writing the strings you want as boundaries as, well, strings?

```
SELECT * FROM table_with_items WHERE column_with_value BETWEEN '43A' AND '64X';
```

Comment: If this is not working, you are omitting some part of the problem or error that you are seeing.  The query in this answer yields values like `55B` and `60Z` while excluding values like `65X` and `100Z`.  Providing more information about your problem makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: I don't get any errors - the items are just not listed. The solution now i'm working on, is to split the numbers from the the characters and compare each... but (f.i.) if i have values between 1A and 100000000000Z it would take a while to calculate...